# R Loops under conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to achieve the following, I have been reading a lot about the tidyverse and it has allowed me to easily perform some tasks in R, and I am sure it could solve my problem below but I do not understand how:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5),
  Buyer = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
  Seller = c("C","D","C","D","C","D","D","D"),
  Exit = c("0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1"),
  End = c("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1"),
  Begin = c("1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
  Dist_fromBegin = c("0","0","1","1","2","2","3","4"),
  Dist_fromExit = c("4","4","3","3","2","2","1","0")
)
View(Data)
```

I have the following code for Begin:

```
setDT(Data)[order(Month, Buyer, Seller), Begin:= {
  r <- rowid(Buyer, Seller)
  +(r==1L)
}]
```

But I cannot manage to calculate Exit (1 if this is the last date of A dealing with C or D), End (1 if this is the last date for the Buyer "A") and DistanceBegin (Date Exit - Date Begin) and Distance Exit (Date End - Date Exit)

Date End is the last date for which we see the Buyer (here A), while Exit is the last time we record the relationship between "A" and "C" (or D.)

I have tried several things with dplyr and mutate, grouping Buyer Seller and Month, but with no result right now...

THank you in advance,

Comment: Your question is not clear as you did not define how to determine "if this is the last date of A dealing with C or D".  No dates are present in your dataframe.

Comment: Hello @YBS very sorry for this. I have edited the message : Date End is the last date for which we see the Buyer (here A), while Exit is the last time we record the relationship between "A" and "C" (or D.).
Dates are recorded in the column month, this is a reduced example of a large database

Comment: Your question is still not clear as you did not state that your initial dataframe has - only 3 items, namely, Month, Buyer and Seller.  Then you need to calculate based on the rules you specified, and finally what is your expected dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider the initial datarame `df1` to have only Month, Buyer and Seller information, most of your calculations can be done as shown in the code below by just using `mutate`.
I added one more buyer and one more seller for the second buyer just to generalize the solution.  The code below should meet your needs.  You can add more variables as needed.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    Month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5),
    Buyer = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
    Seller = c("C","D","C","D","C","D","D","D")
  )
  df2 <- data.frame(
    Month = c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4),
    Buyer = c(rep("B",8)),
    Seller = c("C","D","C","D","E","D","D","E")
  )
  
  df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
  
  dfe <- df3 %>% 
    group_by(Buyer,Seller) %>% 
    slice(tail(row_number(), 1)) %>% mutate(Exit=1, DateExit=Month)
  
  dfe1 <- dfe %>% select(Month,Buyer,Seller,Exit)
  dfe2 <- dfe %>% select(Buyer,Seller,DateExit)
  
  df4 <- merge(df3,dfe1, by=c("Month","Buyer","Seller"), all=TRUE)
  df <- left_join(df4,dfe2, by=c("Buyer","Seller"), all=TRUE)
  
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  
  dfa <- df %>% group_by(Buyer) %>%  
    mutate(minM=min(Month),maxM=max(Month)) %>% 
    mutate(Begin = ifelse(minM==Month,1,0),
           End = ifelse(maxM==Month,1,0),
           Dist_fromBegin = (Month - minM),
           Dist_fromEnd = (maxM - Month),
           Dist_Begin2Exit = (DateExit - minM),
           Dist_Exit2End = (maxM - DateExit),
           Distance2Exit = (DateExit - Month)
           ) %>% select(-minM,-maxM)
  dfb <- dfa[order(dfa$Buyer,dfa$Month,dfa$Seller,dfa$Exit),]
  dfb

>   dfb
# A tibble: 16 x 12
# Groups:   Buyer [2]
   Month Buyer Seller  Exit DateExit Begin   End Dist_fromBegin Dist_fromEnd Dist_Begin2Exit Dist_Exit2End Distance2Exit
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1 A     C          0        3     1     0              0            4               2             2             2
 2     1 A     D          0        5     1     0              0            4               4             0             4
 3     2 A     C          0        3     0     0              1            3               2             2             1
 4     2 A     D          0        5     0     0              1            3               4             0             3
 5     3 A     C          1        3     0     0              2            2               2             2             0
 6     3 A     D          0        5     0     0              2            2               4             0             2
 7     4 A     D          0        5     0     0              3            1               4             0             1
 8     5 A     D          1        5     0     1              4            0               4             0             0
 9     1 B     C          0        2     1     0              0            3               1             2             1
10     1 B     D          0        4     1     0              0            3               3             0             3
11     2 B     C          1        2     0     0              1            2               1             2             0
12     3 B     D          0        4     0     0              2            1               3             0             1
13     3 B     D          0        4     0     0              2            1               3             0             1
14     3 B     E          0        4     0     0              2            1               3             0             1
15     4 B     D          1        4     0     1              3            0               3             0             0
16     4 B     E          1        4     0     1              3            0               3             0             0
```

Comment: thank you this is what I have been looking for !  Somehow `Begin = ifelse(minM==Month,1,0),
           End = ifelse(maxM==Month,1,0)` did not work for me,so I replaced them with `dfe3 <- df3 %>% 
    group_by(Buyer,Seller) %>% 
    slice(head(row_number(), 1)) %>% mutate(Begin=1, DateBegin=Month) 
dfe4 <- df3 %>% 
    group_by(Buyer) %>% 
    slice(tail(row_number(), 1)) %>% mutate(End=1, DateEnd=Month)` and then I merged them. Thank you a lot for your time and sorry for the delay of my answer

Comment: Depending the version of R, some adjustment might be necessary.  You can accept the answer if I have answered your query.